# Accessing Files From Web Document Root

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 3.0 and Tomcat.

I have a bean that has a property whose value should be a path rooted from the web document root. For example, I would specify its value in a Spring configuration file as following.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.stackoverflow.Bean">
    <property name="path" value="/WEB-INF/foo.xml" />
</bean>
```

Where do I take this value to so that I can read the file? Does Spring/Spring MVC provide a transparent way to access resources within the document root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the real path to the resource you will need to have access to `ServletContext`

One way to achieve this will be to make your `com.stackoverflow.Bean implement ServletContextAware` interface. Upon restart, the server should hand over an instance of ServletContext to this bean (you will have to include the following code)

```
private ServletContext ctx;
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    ctx = servletContext;
}
```

Finally, use `ctx.getRealPath(path)` to get the real path to the resource.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using Spring classes directly in you POJO you could inject the path property as a [Resource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) object. Spring will handle the conversion from java.lang.String to org.springframework.core.io.Resource for you. So it should work with the XML that you posted in your question.

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class Bean {

    private Resource resource;

    public void setPath(final Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
         // Use resource.getFile() to get java.io.File
         // or resource.getInputStream() to get java.io.InputStream
    }
}
```

See the [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) for more information on resources.

Answer (score -1):

I'll assume you have a good reason for NOT putting foo.xml in WEB-INF/classes.  It's a simple matter of loading a resource from the CLASSPATH for that directory.

Perhaps a Resource can be had using the "file:WEB-INF/foo.xml" designation would work.

Comment: You see how all Spring configuration files, Apache Tiles files, and Struts configuration files are located in /WEB-INF? The file I have is of similar nature. I just want to be consistent.

Comment: "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds" - Ralph Waldo Emerson.  Make it work first; then worry about consistency.

Comment: It's been working fine for a long time and I'm refactoring it. It would be fun to work with configuration files scattered all over the place. Who needs the convention followed by Apache projects and Spring, when we have a genius named duffymo?. You're just as brilliant as your answer.

Comment: Did you try the Resource suggestion that I gave you?  bmathews seconded it three hours after I posted mine, but his was voted up.

Comment: "scattered all over the place" - moving all non-configuration files from /WEB-INF to /WEB-INF/classes doesn't merit that in my view.  And Spring requires that you put the *-servlet.xml in /WEB-INF, but all the others can be loaded from any directory you choose using the ContextLoaderListener.  I'm not sure why you're so upset or see this as such a big problem.